# FFmpeg uses all memory and crashes when inputs used multiple times in filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

If I define some dummy filter_complex say:

```
[3:v]split=2[3_1][3_2]
[3_1]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[1]
[3_2]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[2]
[4:v]split=2[4_1][4_2]
[4_1]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[3]
[4_2]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[4]
[1][2][3][4]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[video_out]
```

FFmpeg uses all the memory and crashes. What might be the reason?
The same happens for:

```
[3:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[1]
[3:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[2]
[4:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[3]
[4:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[4]
[1][2][3][4]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[video_out]
```

I know the examples are silly but I am here asking about why this uses all my RAM? (and how to work around this)

This works great by the way (inputs used once):

```
[3:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[1]
[4:v]format=yuv420p,scale='640:360',setsar='1/1'[2]
[1][2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[video_out]
```

UPDATE:
The full log. While it runs it reaches 2GB memory usage in about 5s and continues to grow.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f lavfi -i nullsrc=s=640x360 -i 1000211803.mp4 -i 220710.mp4 -i 223157.mp4 -i 232365.mp4 -i 1000000046.mp4 -i 1000238585.mp4 -filter_complex_script "c:\Users\wojtek\Desktop\Development\video_grid_ffmpeg_nodejs\filter_complex_param.txt" -vsync 2 -map "[video_out]" out.mp4
ffmpeg version n4.3.1-20-g8a2acdc6da Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --disable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --disable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtwolame --disable-libvidstab --disable-libx264 --disable-libx265 --disable-libxavs2 --disable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'nullsrc=s=640x360':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1000211803.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 00:55:35.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 136 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 134 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '220710.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 00:57:21.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 102 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 99 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '223157.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 01:01:11.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 156 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 153 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '232365.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 01:01:07.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 127 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 124 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1000000046.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 00:52:17.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 190 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 188 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1000238585.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
  Duration: 00:50:58.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 106 kb/s
    Stream #6:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 376x210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 188:105], 103 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> format
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 6130 fps=610 q=20.6 Lsize=    5334kB time=00:03:24.30 bitrate= 213.9kbits/s speed=20.3x
video:5307kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.507003%
```

The above has been produced using this filter_complex parameter value:

```
[3:v]format=yuv420p,scale='-1:360',crop='640:in_h',setsar='1/1'[i2_640_360]
[3:v]format=yuv420p,scale='-1:360',crop='640:in_h',setsar='1/1'[i2_320_360]
[4:v]format=yuv420p,scale='-1:360',crop='640:in_h',setsar='1/1'[i3_320_360]
[4:v]format=yuv420p,scale='-1:360',crop='640:in_h',setsar='1/1'[i3_640_360]
[i2_640_360][i2_320_360][i3_320_360][i3_640_360]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[video_out]
```

I did not wait for it to give the out of memory error.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this issue. Recommend not using `[1]`, `[2]`, etc as these are special labels reserved to refer to the input files, but I did not test to see how it works if using them as filter output labels. Use a custom label, such as `[1v]`, `[2v]`, etc.

Comment: There's no error checking, so `[1:v]filter1[0:v];[0:v]filter2` will feed the output of filter1 to filter2.

Comment: @llogan Unfortunately it does not matter what labels I use. The issue is still there.

Comment: @ed22 What's the minimal command that still has this problem? Eliminate any unnecessary inputs and filters.

Comment: This command spikes at 6GB of memory usage in 20s and then drops to about 1.5GB slowly: [3:v]split=3[a][b][c];[a][b][c]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[video_out] . If I split to 2 pads instead of 3 it spikes at about 3-4GB instead. I believe it is strongly related to the problem described above.

Comment: It seems that each 'split' output needs a 'fifo' filter. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the outputs of the [split/asplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) filters need to be put through [fifo/afifo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fifo_002c-afifo) filters respectively before further processing. Don't know why exactly.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with (a)split as partial example #2 and example #4 do not use split and still experience OOM.

Comment: @llogan From what I understand reusing inputs in filter complex is similar to using split. I am not sure if reused inputs need the fifo filter or if it fixes the problem in that case.